# Unable to trigger SP 2013 Workflow using Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow-manager, visual-studio-wf

i have created a sharepoint 2013 workflow using visual studio designer 2013 and it contains just one action - writetohistory , it simply writes a message to the workflowtasklist and its a farm solution and i have deployed the solution.

After the deployment to this workflow to a document library , am able to see the workflow name in the workflow settings for the document library.
But when i added an item in the doc lib, my workflow is NOT triggering.
Am stuck with this strange issue.

Has anyone faced this, previously?
[image: VS-DESIGNER-SURFACE]

[image: wf-not-triggered]

Comment: Have you configured a Workflow Manager Farm?

Comment: Yes ,I have configured wf manager 1.0 refresh cu2 ,service bus 1.1

Comment: Great! And what if you create a simple workflow with SharePoint Designer? Do you get the same result then?

Comment: am trying with spd now. will update here.